# How do I write a function that accepts Array<UInt8> or ArraySlice<UInt8>?

Tags: swift

What I'm trying to do is to parse (part of) a binary protocol (MQTT) by writing a function like this:

```
func readString(bytes: Array<UInt8> OR ArraySlice<UInt8>) -> (string: String?, remainingBytes: ArraySlice<UInt8>?)
```

I know about polymorphism but I would prefer to have one function.

I have written a function (using generics), that accepts an `Array` or `ArraySlice` of `UnsignedIntegerType` but I only want `UInt8`. It seems like a straightforward thing to do but so far I haven't came up with a good solution...

Comment: What is an ArraySlice? Do you mean Slice?

Comment: @matt Slice was renamed to ArraySlice in Swift 1.2 beta 2 (or 3).

Comment: Darn! I missed that, and I happened to be sitting at my older-system computer at the time I was reading this. I am going to have to update this computer to Yosemite. And _I don't want to!_ Okay, I'm calming down now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is, first, forget about the return type and think just about what this function should accept as its parameter. In particular,  think about what Array and Slice have in common and write a generic specifying that. They are both **MutableCollectionType** and **Sliceable**. And basically nothing else in the world is (nothing else that you are likely to use, that is).

Moreover, you want the element type to be UInt8.

So now just say that, the way a generic lets you say it:

```
func readString<T:MutableCollectionType 
    where T:Sliceable, T.Generator.Element == UInt8>(bytes: T) {
        // ...
}
```

And here's a test:

```
let arr = [UInt8(1),UInt8(2),UInt8(3)]
readString(arr) // compiles
readString(arr[1...2]) // compiles
```

A nice thing about this formulation is that the compiler will test, if it can, to see if you are calling with legal integer types. For example, this compiles, because all the integers are small and positive:

```
readString([1,2,3])
```

But this doesn't even compile, because the compiler knows that a negative integer can't be a UInt8:

```
readString([-1,2,3])
```

Comment: Of course a perhaps simpler, but not as elegant, work around could be to create a slice of the whole array `array[0..<array.count]`

Comment: Or the other way: convert your slice to an array - `Array(ar[1...2])` - when you pass it. But I tried to answer the question you actually asked, and it's a perfectly reasonable one: after all, lots of built-in Swift global methods take an array or a slice, and this sort of thing is how they do it.

Comment: The problem with converting to Array is that it would probably allocate memory for it and that was exactly the thing I was trying to avoid. You provided exactly the answer I was looking for.